# How to make one radio button option checked by default angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make one radio button option should be checked by default.
I tried to give `ng-model`, and `ng-init` but its not working.

My Html :

```
<div bindonce ng-repeat="row in results.favorites" style="padding: 0px 10px; white-space: nowrap; border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef; border-top: 1px solid #eee;  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;">
    <input type="radio" ng-click="setFavoriteDashboard(row.id)" ng-model="selectedRow" name="favRadioSel" style="opacity: 1;" class="pointer"/>
    <span bo-text="row.title" style="margin: 10px; position: relative; top: 3px;"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

My JS:

```
$scope.results = {
  favorites: [{
    id: "WatchList1",
    title: "WatchList1"
  }, {
    id: "WatchList2",
    title: "WatchList2"
  }, {
    id: "WatchList3",
    title: "WatchList3"
  }]
};
$scope.selectedRow = "WatchList1";
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/KA9HyQ3bHxJo2Cm9qFm3?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rh5xh930BukHSTMF8LQp?p=preview).

Instead of using `ng-value="{{row.id}}"`, use `ng-value="row.id"`.

Please check documentation of [`ngValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue):

```
<input
  [ng-value="string"]>
...
</input>
```

Comment: scope variable should be in parent..rather than in `ng-repeat`..look at mine answer..

Answer (score 0):

Set `$scope.selectedRow` to `$scope.results.favorites[0].id` and use `value` instead of `ng-value`.

**How it works**: `value` of the radio button is set to `id` and `ng-model` is set to `selectedRow`, according to your plunker. Thus, if you want to make the first value of the array a default, you just assign `selectedRow` to its `id`

[See plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LC6eBqlx81O0Yvub4YRO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$parent` to point to parent scope `selectedRow` variable as `ng-repeat` does create an child scope, & also you need to use `ng-value` attribute value without interpolation.

**Markup**

```
<input type="radio" 
 ng-model="$parent.selectedRow" 
 ng-value="row.id" name="favRadioSel" 
 style="opacity: 1;" 
 class="pointer" />
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mrvp4dc0lQa1AulIrfcv?p=preview)